# mapbox not showing roads at zoom level 8.*

Tags: android, caching, zooming, mapbox, tiles

I am using mapbox in an Android app. At a zoom level from 8.0 to 8.999.. it doesn't show roads on parts of the map. I does show borders though.
Zoom levels < 8 and >= 9 seem OK.

[image]

Strangely enough this only affects a part of Germany. Not all tiles behave like this, as you can see on the second image

[image]

Has anybody had a similar experience?
I do not think I have bad tiles in the cache, since I've seen identical behavior on a 2nd device.

Comment: This problem is fixed but the cache might still contain some problematic tiles. Could you report directly to Mapbox if this continues to happen?

Comment: Was the problem fixed right this moment? Or since a while? Because it still doesn't work on my device. Anyway in the meantime I created my own style as a workaround. And I had already reported the bug to Mapbox this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the standard style called `"Streets"`, which seems to have a strange bug (and which might even be about to be fixed, see comment above).

Anyway, I gave up on it, went to `https://www.mapbox.com/studio/` and created my own style based on the `Basic Template`. It took some time, but it was very easy.
My own style now looks almost as the "Streets" style, and it does not have the bug, so I can now move on.